# Design issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

**Issue**

1. In design background is fit.
2. In attributes background is set to `fill_parent`
3. In phone it has gap from both sides!

**Any idea why I get padding in phone and how to remove it?**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Solved** by `android:scaleType="fitXY"`